# Wordpress Multisite Common Content

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Have recently installed a Wordpress Multisite with network sites setup as a sub-folder under the root main domain. I have searched all over Google and on here (SO) but couldnt find a suitable answer to my query.

Brief background: Basically the business organizes multiple biz events throughout the year. Earlier, each event had its own website which was managed by me seperately. To streamline the workflow and management since the number of events were increasing over time, i realised it would make sense to do a multisite since we have now over 6-7 events and managing their individual websites would become cumbersome over time.

The site structure im using is ...
Main site - bizsite-dot-com
Each event sub-site - bizsite-dot-com/event01 | bizsite-dot-com/event02

Now although the event sites are inherently different in design and content, there are some pages like the 'contact us' and 'about us' page which are common to all sites. My query is, is there are way for me to have that content available in a single page at the parent (bizsite-dot-com/contacts) and this content can be pulled into each of the event site themes. Reason being, sometimes the contacts change, people come and go, and we have to make the changes in all the sites. So it would make sense to change it one place and have that reflected in all the network sites.

Hope i have been clear in my explanation and thank you advance for putting up with my long query and your help for the same.